# Need to make changes to Paypal website pro templete, Where is it located?

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

I am trying to find out the template for Paypal website pro payment page that i see in contribution page. I am not abale to locate it!! Can anyone help me to locate this file please?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

templates/CRM/Core/BillingBlock.tpl

Note that the template is quite programmatic and gets in pretty much all of its info via template variables. I suspect you will benefit from reading the developer documentation which will help you with the Civi learning curve.

Comment: Thank you, I just want to have a look for learning couple of things....